# Send Newsletter weekly using Sendgrid Web API

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am developing a project using PHP in which I am using sendgrid web API. In which, I want to send Newsletter on every week or month on a specified date by user.

I don't know how can I manage this on sendgrid.
Can anyone please help me and give me solution for that.

Comment: no idea about snedgrid, but the scheduling could be done  with a cron job

Comment: I know that I can do that by cron job but I want to know is sendgrid providing any facility for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sendgrid does not provide any service this kind of.

If you want to handle this sending of newsletter recurring then you can manage by managing database and by cron job on your server.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the newsletter API, which is documented here:

> http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Newsletter_API/index.html

Specifically, you can use the API to schedule deliveries using the schedule endpoint:

> http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Newsletter_API/schedule.html

There's no PHP wrapper, so you'll need to make the requests with curl or something similar.

Comment: I am looking for a recursive schedule using which I can send newsletter to a list on a specific date and time on every month. And I found that send grid is not providing any facility.

Answer (score 0):

**Download Sendgrid PHP wrapper from here :**

https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php

```
   include 'path/to/sendgrid-php/SendGrid_loader.php';

   //Initialize the SendGrid object with your SendGrid credentials:
   $sendgrid = new SendGrid('username', 'password');

   //Create a new SendGrid Mail object and add your message details
   $mail = new SendGrid\Mail();
   $mail->
   addTo('foo@bar.com')->
   setFrom('me@bar.com')->
   setSubject('Subject goes here')->
   setText('Hello World!')->
   setHtml('Hello World!');

   //Send it using the Web API like so:
   $sendgrid->
   web->
   send($mail);
```

Check Sendgrid API documentation here
http://sendgrid.com/docs/Code_Examples/php.html

Edit:

Setup cron job on the server to run this script weekly or monthly.

Comment: I know that I can do that using cron job but I want a way in sendgrid handels all that things